# How to specify a picking policy in rack pick block? - Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

**INTRODUCTION**

I have 5 pallet racks with 3 levels each.
I store items in them using a rack store block, specifying dynamically the palletRack where to store them. In order to keep track of the pallet rack where the items are being saved, I save the reference to the pallet rack in a variable inside the item itself. Then I pick items from the correct shelf using a rack pick block and specifying as pallet rack `agent.myVariableToStorePalletRack`.

[rack pick description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUiF2.jpg)

[rack store description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bui4j.jpg)

**PROBLEM**

The problem is that I need items being picked in a specific order, picking every item from palletRack1, then every item in palletRack2, then every item in palletRack3 and so on, but I don't know how to specify this picking policy.
How can I achieve this?

**POSSIBLE SOLUTIONS I ALREADY TRIED**

I already tried to put a queue before the rack pick block to sort items, but this is not working.

[queue description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8u0RN.png)

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: can you clarify & rephrase the question, boil it down to the core problem that you need help with. Not clear currently :) Follow this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry, I edited the question. I hope that it is much more understandable now.

Answer (score 0):

You must  implement this manually, i.e. through a function that sorts all items by the rack they are in and then tells items, in that order, to leave their storage.

Storage itself should be a "Wait" object, so items are stored forever, until that function tells them to leave and call a resource to pick them up.

Best log all stored items in a collection as well when they are stored. this way, you can easily loop through them when it is time for pickup.